# How do you use the express framework but store a users data in a SQL Server database?

Tags: sql, sql-server

How do you use the express framework but store a users data with a built in a SQL Server database?

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do this with ExpressJS. You were just a google search away. It is clearly mentioned in the ExpressJS Documentation.

Check out [this link](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/database-integration.html#mysql%22here%22) for integration with MySQL, PostgreSQL etc.